# what is a Möbius transformation with no fixed points?

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

is there a Mobius transformation with no fixed points?

I have the equation $$\frac{az+b}{cz+d}=z\implies cz^2+dz-az-b=0$$ given the fixed points when this is true. So if we set $c\ne 0$ we get two roots and thus two fixed points, but in the case of $c=0$ we get one fixed point. I can't see where there is a case with no fixed points?

Comment: If $d=a$ and $c=0$ then this is a translation by the factor $b/a$. It fixes infinity. But that's it.

Comment: @Eoin : But probably one would want to include $\infty$ as a member of both the domain and the codomain, so what is asked for is impossible. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thank you for pointing that out to me.

Answer (score 3):

If $c\neq 0$ there are one or two fixed points by the quadratic formula.  If $c=0$ and $d\neq a$, then $z=\dfrac{b}{d-a}$ is a fixed point.  If $c=0$ and $d=a$, and $b=0$ and every point is a fixed point, because the transformation is the identity.  If $c=0$, $d=a$, and $b\neq 0$, then it will fix the point at infinity.

Comment: Note that if $c=0$, then $\infty$ will always be a fixed point.